# Can't execute javascript on Android with Kindle Fire

Tags: android, webview, kindle-fire

I have an application which needs to execute javascript in a Webview.

When I test it on mobile/tablet/note (Samsung Galaxy S3, Sony TX, Samsung N10.1...), it runs perfectly. However, when I test it on **Kindle Fire (Android 4.3)**, the javascript code which I wrote in html file doesn't execute, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I got the answer. **I must add the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript when running on Android 4.2 or higher.**

Followed this http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html